# Can we use \curvepnodes and \psnline to replace the concatenated points passed to \psrline?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

[image]

Can we use `\curvepnodes` and `\psnline` to get the same result as what the following code produces?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido,pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\def\points{}%
\multido{\r=0.0+0.1}{90}{\xdef\points{\points(!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}}
\psset{showpoints,dotstyle=o,dotscale=2}
\rput(-1,0){\expandafter\psrline\points}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: The segments have equal length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do that:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido,pst-node,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \curvepnodes[plotpoints=90]{0}{89}{%
    -1 0        % starting point
     0 1 t {% start increment end 
      0.1 mul sqrt 700 mul 1 exch PtoC % the coordinates of the relative vector 
      3 -1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch  % add the coordinates to the intermediate result on the stack
    } for }{P}
  \psnline[showpoints,dotstyle=o,dotscale=2](0,89){P} 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The main difference is, that one needs to use absolute coordinates for all nodes. This is done by iterating inside the Postscript expression of `\curvepnodes`.

The values of `plotpoints`, `tmin` and `tmax` (the first two parameters to `\curvepnodes`) are choosen such, that `t` is integer.

So the Postscript part sums up all relative vectors from `0` to `t`. The `-1 0` gives the starting point.

The result is the same as yours :)

[image]

Here is a variant, which saves the intermediate results as `/myX` and `/myY` in the `tx@NodeDict`, which is much more efficient:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido,pst-node,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \pstVerb{tx@NodeDict begin /myX -1 def /myY 0 def end }%
  \curvepnodes[plotpoints=90]{0}{89}{%
    myX myY
    t 0.1 mul sqrt 700 mul 1 exch PtoC
    3 -1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch
    2 copy /myY ED /myX ED
  }{P}
  \psnline[showpoints,dotstyle=o,dotscale=2](0,89){P} 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `-1 0` is the starting point, `0` the initial value for the `for` loop, `1` the increment and `t` the limit. The `cvi` converts a value to integer. That was necessary for my first try with `repeat`, but not needed for `for`, so I removed it. I added some comments in the Postscript part and some remarks.

Comment: Is there an accessible constant that represents `dt` (increment in `t`) where `dt=(tmax-tmin)/(plotpoints-1)`? Sometimes I need it for other calculation done after invoking `\curvepnodes`.

Comment: Yes, this is defined as `dt`.

Comment: Using `\curvepnodes` seems to be inefficient as for each node the calculation starts from 0, does not it?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot No, only my implementation was inefficient. See my edit for a more efficient way.

Comment: What is the purpose to defined the temporary variables in a dictionary? I tried without a dictionary and it still works.

Comment: Because I found it to be cleaner. Otherwise you would have the initial values stored in another dictionary than the following ones, which are redefined in `\curvepnodes`.

Comment: I don't know about dictionary, is it used to avoid name clash like namespace in C# or C/C++ programming language?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the purposes of dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\psset{showpoints,dotstyle=o,dotscale=2}
\psStartPoint[P](0,0)
\multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{90}{\psVector[arrows=-](!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}
\uput[0](P50){P50}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is nice but not using `\curvepnodes` so it is just the simplification of my code in the question.